# Is it possible to completely disable the blur event on a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to completely prevent a contenteditable div from being able to lose focus.

I have tried all of the following within the `blur` handler:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
return false;
```

The only solution I have found is to use a setTimeout and reFocus the element like so:

```
$(element).on('blur', function(){
     var el = $(this);

     setTimeout(function(){
         el.focus();
     },5);
});
```

Although this keeps the element focussed the caret will of course move to the beginning rather than keeping its current selection status/position.

Before I go about writing code to store the caret position/selection on blur and reposition it on focus I was hoping that someone else had found a way to completely prevent a blur event altogether.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if they click outside the browser window?  Or open another tab?  Or close the browser?  You can't really prevent that; web browsers don't provide for that sort of interaction (or lack of interaction).

Comment: Also Safari is quite picky about paying attention to `.focus()` calls.

Comment: I suppose the experience I am looking for is that of 'google docs' i.e. the editing area keeps the caret flashing and in position wherever the user clicks in the browser.  It is less about preventing the blur and more about providing a consistent caret position/selection.  Of course preventing the blur would be the easiest way to do so would it not?  If the only way is by writing selection/position saving/restoring code as I suggested that is fine, I will have to do so.  In which case write up your comment as a relevant answer and I will accept it. cheers.

Comment: Well I'm interested to see whether anybody has a suggestion; your explanation in that comment about *why* you want to do this adds a lot of good information to the question. I don't have much experience with applications that need to do something like that.